Putative Value of Niche Units of Measure (Natural Gas)
In the State of Connecticut (for example, this happens elsewhere as well) Natural Gas is denominated in Cubic Feet (ccf, actually, which is Hundred Cubic Feet). The US EIA also reports natural gas statistics in cubic feet.
However, if you sold an engineer, chemist, scientist, or other technical professional, "one cubic foot of gas" and they were the trusting sort (and thus made the sort of assumption those fields commonly make), they would angrily come back to you and demand to know why you delivered ~5.14% less gas than was agreed (you sold them 1.1984 moles, while they were expecting 1.2633).
The reason this would happen is because they would have assumed that "cubic foot of natural gas" implied standard temperature and pressure as is importantly understood in their profession(s) as 32 degrees F (0 degrees C), and 1 Atmosphere of pressure (29.92 inches of mercury) - the conditions under which pure water freezes at sea level.
The statutory definition according to the State of Connecticut, and US EIA, of a 'cubic foot of natural gas,' however is NOT defined by STP (Standard Temperature and Pressure), it is instead 60 Degrees F, and 30.00 inches of mercury.
If it were just the inches of mercury being rounded off, I would assume it was someone just being lazy with their math but the massive change away from standard temperature causes a much smaller amount of gas (1.1984 moles vs. 1.2633 moles).
Recognizing that standard temperature and pressure has, itself, been a moving target (in 1982 it was re-specified by IUPAC, for example) some drift and/or change over time (such as the shift by EIA in 1965 to a different pressure assumption), there is still a general disagreement between the parameters of 'cubic foot of natural gas' for purposes of market transactions, and 'cubic foot of any gas' for virtually any other purpose.
What is the rationale or economic value behind such niche unit definitions, particularly ones that clash with accepted principles of engineering, science, etc?
